# How to change default Options in BigQuery console (Web UI), especially uncheck "Use Legacy SQL"?

Tags: google-bigquery

Every time when I Compose Query have to uncheck box "Use Legacy SQL" after reveal this by clicking 'Show Options'.

It's waste of time because in most cases I use standard SQL.

I know there is some workaround for above by 'Setting a query prefix' (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql),
but typing all the time #standardSQL could be also annoying.

Is there any third party plugin or other option to change this default behaviour?

---

in the new console **standardSQL** is default option, just click ->  [image]

Comment: I need to add that auto completion should also work on Standard SQL.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - does BQMate have anything for this?

Comment: @GrahamPolley I think I can add this to BQMate. In internal tool I have already `standard sql as a default` + `change default in preferences` + `switch version available w/o any extra clicks` + `version auto-detection`

Comment: @Pentium10 - autocompletion does fully work on StandardSQL - are there specific examples where it didn't work for you.

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky it doesn't work at all when you have wildcards or you use more tables in the query:  `prj.dataset.ga_sessions_*`, also it doesn't work when #standardSQL pragma is used.

Comment: @GrahamPolley - check BQ Mate (v1.5.87) - I just added keyboard shortcut and button to UI - and see my answer for details

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky also you need to add info if a table is partitioned by or not, currently cannot see that on the interface thus also _partitiontime doesn't autocomplete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While not exactly the answer for your question - but BigQuery team is working on more flexible project config, such that users will be able to change different project level settings, including default SQL dialect for the project.

Comment: any (kind of) ETA?

Comment: No ETA at this time - and we would love to see this in BQMate in the meantime (we are waiting for this feature too!)

Comment: check latest version - I think it is reasonably good and useful - at least till Web UI will get its own

Comment: Glad to know that you are working on this. I hope to get it soon ;)

Comment: It is now 2 years and I have not seen a solution for this productivity killer. It should not be hard to give an option on some level (e.g. User or project) to keep that checkbox unticked by default... @mosha Where is this issue tracked?

Answer (score 3):

> ... have to uncheck box "Use Legacy SQL" after reveal this by clicking 'Show Options'.
>   It's waste of time ...

If you haven't used [**BQ Mate**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigquery-mate/nepgdloeceldecnoaaegljlichnfognh) yet - please try
I just added (sql) button to do quick toggle between Legacy and Standard SQL

[image]

It is easily accessible so no waste of time
Also you can now use ALT+L to do exactly the same (switch between SQL Versions)

So to quickly `Switch SQL Version` - press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or `Click` on <kbd>SQL</kbd> button

Hope you will find it useful!

> Update

Added `Save As Default Version` - <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or `Double Click` on <kbd>SQL</kbd> button

If you "saved" default SQL Version  - next time you open Web UI - SQL Version will be "automatically" switched to Default one.

If within the Web UI Session you close and open Editor - it will always keep the latest chosen version - so you don't need to do even one extra click

Hope, now it is even more useful :o)

---

Affiliation notice: I am the author and only developer of BQMate

Comment: Consider adding a link in your answer for readers who aren't familiar with BQ Mate. (As an aside--nice feature!)

Comment: It's handy, especially shortcut key but it is still not default option when I click "Compose Query".
Is it possible to do it in that way?

Regarding "BigQuery Mate" I have some concerns about permission: "Read and change your data on bigquery.cloud.google.com".
How can I know that your plugin is not vulnerable and can I give it access to production data?

Comment: @D.M.- I actually haven't planned for any updates with tool nowadays (especially before Next'17) because it is obvious that Web UI must be improved in many different areas and most likely BigQuery UI team is working on this - so I was more waiting for this to happen. Meantime, I've done yesterday's new feature for BQMate during lunch break just to address "waste of time" aspect. If one-click switch is still considered not enough - I can spend today's lunch break to add remembering your last used sql version (within the tab session) - should be simple - see for version change from current .57

Comment: @D.M. - try now  - improved switch logic and added default behavior

Comment: Thank you very much for fast update within plugin but meantime I got to know that can not use any third party plugins in such context.... :/ Anyway I think it will be useful for a lot of users of BigQuery and BQ Mate. I need to wait for official support of above functionality.

Comment: After a carefull read I assume you are affiliated with BQ mate. This is fine, but please state it explicitly somewhere in the answer.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - I am not just affiliated  - I am the author and only developer of BQMate which is explicitly stated on BQMate Web Store :o)