# Setting default processing location for project

Tags: google-bigquery

We have moved all our projects to EU and everything most works fine without specifying locations.

However on our projects queries like:

```
select 1
```

Will fail with:

```
Cannot run query: project does not have the reservation in the data region
```

You need to specify the location on the console. This also happens with queries in out ETLs via Airflow.

Queries affected are those that do not have a specific table:
 * Select from GoogleDrive

- Select from constant or math values.

Is there a way to define a project wide default processing location?

Comment: Hi Cloud Support here! Can you raise a private issue using the following link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149 Please add there your Project Number. (and some job IDs failing would be useful as well).  / The processing location can be defined when each job is run, there is currently no wide default option available that would solve your issue

Comment: your question is included in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42131534/how-to-change-default-options-in-bigquery-console-web-ui-especially-uncheck